# Maven tomcat plugin with extra war files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I have a working war project which is being run under the maven tomcat plugin.
Now I want to run an extra war in this embeded tomcat instance. I searched for ways to do this and found:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webapps>
            <webapp>
                <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
                <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
            </webapp>
        </webapps>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried to execute it and got:

```
[INFO] Deploying dependency wars
[INFO] Deploy warfile: [workspace_war_project_loc]\target\classes to contextPath: /test
[ERROR] org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: The source must not be a directory.
```

any help? :(

Update: this was while running in eclipse with "resolve workspace artifacts" option active. If I turn this off, the build completes successfully, but then when I try to access the servlets from the extra war, they're not available.. :( As I don't have the manager available in the embeded tomcat instance I cannot check what's there..

any help?

Comment: Did u happen to solve this ?

Comment: nop, had to rethink the problem and keep working with one single war :(